# Finding the right tag for a picture from Instagram grid feed with selenium (Instagram Bot)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, bots, instagram

Good morning !

I have recently come accross a problem while developing a bot for Instagram out of curiosity.

I am trying to automate liking with selenium. The program is supposed to **launch a session**, **log into instagram**, **fetch a picture** from a specific **#** and **execute a bunch of actions** from this point on.

The only problem lies in the line responsible for clicking on the image of the instagram feed grid.

So far the line that was responsible for retrieving the image and clicking on it was the following :

`first_pic = browser.find_element("xpath", "//div[@class='_ac7v _aang'][4]/div/a")`

The path specified was found using the console in chrome and by inspecting the image I wanted the bot to click on.

However the program suddenly stopped working, I suspect instagram somehow changed the name of the class or something like this.

I tried repeating the process to find the new xpath but I just cannot find any path that seems to be working. Everytime I inspect an image, it seems to be lacking the **a** tag in the HTML code. There is only the **img** tag.

When inspecting the image I want to click on the following tags appear :

```html
<div class="_aabd _aa8k _a131">
 <a class="class_name" href="url" ...>
  <div class="_aagu">
    <div class="_aagv">
      <img alt=text crossorigin=text class="x5yr21d xu96u03 x10l6tqk x13vifvy x87ps6o xh8yej3" src=url style="object-fit: cover;">
    </div>
    <div class="_aagw">
    </div>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

I tried fetching the 10th element to access a specific picture in the grid (all the grid pictures have the same class name). I tried :

first_pic = browser.find_element("xpath", "//div[@class='_aabd _aa8k  _al3l'][10]/a")

But it didn't work

Comment: Can you share the HTML mark-up of the desired element in the form of text?

Comment: Yes I'd love that ! can you tell me what do you mean by mark-up ? is it the `<>` tag that holds the image that you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes that's right. Try to share not only the image tag `<>`, but also few more tags around it.

Comment: I edited the post for more lisibility :)

Comment: Try this XPATH to locate the 10th element - `(//div[contains(@class,'_aabd _aa8k _a131')])[10]//img`.

Comment: So I fiddled around with your syntax and mine and it appears that ```(//div[@class='_aabd _aa8k  _al3l'])[10]/a``` did the trick :D Thanks !